# How to fill the missing multiple columns and rows for pivot table in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Is there any method or function to fill missing multiple columns and rows for pivot table in python?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

csvfile = StringIO("""Date;Cat;Type;Value
01-Jan;AA;S;1
02-Jan;AA;F;2
02-Jan;BB;T;3
04-Jan;BB;T;3
05-Jan;CC;T;2
05-Jan;DD;T;1
05-Jan;BB;S;4
05-Jan;AA;S;2
05-Jan;DD;S;4""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = ';')
pt = pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'Value', index=['Cat', 'Type'], columns= ['Date'], aggfunc = np.sum, fill_value = 0)
pt
```

The above code result shows as below, the Type columns are missing values (F,S,T) for some Cat, 03-Jan column is missing:

```
Cat|Type|01-Jan|02-Jan|04-Jan|05-Jan|
---+----+------+------+------+------+
AA |F   |      |     2|      |      |
   |S   |     1|      |      |     2|
BB |S   |      |      |      |     4|
   |T   |      |     3|     3|      |
CC |T   |      |      |      |     2|
DD |S   |      |      |      |     4|
   |T   |      |      |      |     1|
```

But the expected result want as:

```
Cat|Type|01-Jan|02-Jan|03-Jan|04-Jan|05-Jan|
---+----+------+------+------+------+------+
AA |F   |      |     2|      |      |      |
   |S   |     1|      |      |      |     2|
   |T   |      |      |      |      |      |
BB |F   |      |      |      |      |      |
   |S   |      |      |      |      |     4|
   |T   |      |     3|      |     3|      |
CC |F   |      |      |      |      |      |
   |S   |      |      |      |      |      |
   |T   |      |      |      |      |     2|
DD |F   |      |      |      |      |      |
   |S   |      |      |      |      |     4|
   |T   |      |      |      |      |     1|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert `df['Type']` to [Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) first:

```
df['Type'] = df['Type'].astype('category')
```

This forces Pandas to show every value with `pivot_table`. It's also good practice to trust Pandas conversion of strings such as `'sum'` to optimised functions. Here's a demo:

```
df['Type'] = df['Type'].astype('category')

pt = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Value', index=['Cat', 'Type'],
                    columns='Date', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)

print(pt)

Date      01-Jan  02-Jan  04-Jan  05-Jan
Cat Type                                
AA  F          0       2       0       0
    S          1       0       0       2
    T          0       0       0       0
BB  F          0       0       0       0
    S          0       0       0       4
    T          0       3       3       0
CC  F          0       0       0       0
    S          0       0       0       0
    T          0       0       0       2
DD  F          0       0       0       0
    S          0       0       0       4
    T          0       0       0       1
```

Comment: @jezrael, Hmm, strange, works for me. Could be a Pandas bug / version difference. I'm admittedly on 0.19.2, but don't *expect* anything to have changed.

Comment: Yes, checked in last `pandas 0.23.4`

Comment: @jezrael, Maybe it's a bug in a new version, will check if I have some time. OP should definitely try this one first in my opinion, it's more memory efficient and cleaner.

Comment: I test it and no added to answer, because not working for me only.

Comment: Can you check it in last pandas version?

Comment: Not now, maybe later :)

Comment: work for me.  How to apply date series for 'Date' column and make it categorical?

Comment: @Alan, No idea, `'Date'` is not a series in the result, it's used as columns.

Answer (score 1):

You need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) after `pivot_table` by all combination of values in `Cat` and `Type` columns:

```
m = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Cat'].unique(),df['Type'].unique()], names=pt.index.names)
pt = pt.reindex(m)
print (pt)
Date      01-Jan  02-Jan  04-Jan  05-Jan
Cat Type                                
AA  S        1.0     0.0     0.0     2.0
    F        0.0     2.0     0.0     0.0
    T        NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
BB  S        0.0     0.0     0.0     4.0
    F        NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    T        0.0     3.0     3.0     0.0
CC  S        NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    F        NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    T        0.0     0.0     0.0     2.0
DD  S        0.0     0.0     0.0     4.0
    F        NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    T        0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0
```